# Mongoose model chain unit testing (Regular Callback)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mongoose, sinon

I am trying to unit test:

```
myModel.find({"id": someId}, callback)
    .sort({timestamp: -1})
    .limit(100)
```

I used sinon-mongoose and came up with the following

```
myModel
    .expects('find').withArgs({"id": 'def'})
    .chain('exec')
    .yields(null, 'abc')
    .chain('sort').withArgs({timestamp: -1})
    .chain('limit').withArgs(100);
```

However, I run into the issue that the done function is not being called and the test times out. Anyone have experience stubbing the regular callback over the exec callback using sinon-mongoose?

If I change my model code to:

```
myModel.find({"id": someId}
    .exec(callback)
    .sort({timestamp: -1})
    .limit(100)
```

The unit test works. Thus, I think it's a problem in stubbing the exec callback vs regular callback.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by writing the following, and not worrying about the callback in the mongoose query test.

```
myModel
    .expects('find').withArgs({"id": 'def'})
    .yields(null, 'abc')
    .chain('sort').withArgs({timestamp: -1})
    .chain('limit').withArgs(100);
```